# Spring security & Wicket + filters

Tags: spring, security, wicket

the main approach to use when securing Wicket application using Spring security is to include such construct in AuthenticatedWebSession:

```
    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager
            .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    authenticated = authentication.isAuthenticated();
```

In opposition to Spring Security authentication request comes within a backend so there is too late for any HTTP Request processing. That said entire Spring Security filter chain is DOWN no-matter what, see this line in the **AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter**:

```
 public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        if (!requiresAuthentication(request, response)) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);

            return;
        }

        // (...) "normal" Spring authentication process which will never take place

        successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
    }
```

Where the requiresAuthentication method checks for the "j_spring_security_check" on the request path. Of course there isn't any in the approach taken.

What's the consequence? Since you rely ONLY on the AuthenticationManager you obtain from the application context itself actions that would normally be triggered in the filter chain just won't happen: for instance Spring remember-me services won't work. Cookies are being set in the filter method which returns prematurely. Cookies can be read, but they do not exist.

**And my question is** - is there a serious Spring Security to Wicket adaptation or not? I mean it should skip the chain but trigger all those actions which would normally be run from within the backend, as Wicket does.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you read/seen https://github.com/thombergs/wicket-spring-security-example ?

Comment: The first thing what makes me wonder is that there is no Wicket security annotations on pages and there are intercept patterns in the spring security config itself. The second thing is that SecurityContextPersistenceFilter and a call httpSession.setAttribute. But still, is it really fully functional? What is more - why do they use session=never?

Comment: Wicket has its own annotation based role security mechanism. So there is no need to use Spring annotation directly, just if you can make an adapter between Spring roles and Wicket roles. Probably have a look to https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Spring+Security+and+Wicket-auth-roles even though that uses a bit older Spring and Wicket, the principle is the same.